# Non-linear symmetry and symmetry at quantum level

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory, gauge-invariance, non-linear-systems, brst

Can anyone explain me what does the statement mean:

> "the BRST symmetry is a non-linear symmetry, so the BRST is also a symmetry at the quantum level"?

What does "at the quantum level" mean? In general I have a symmetry in the classical field theory action and then when I quantize the theory I get a Ward-Takahashi Identity. Is this identity the symmetry at the quantum level? I don't think so since it is a consequence of the non-linearity of the symmetry.
Can anyone clarify this?

Comment: Statement from which reference? Which page?

Comment: It was in the lecture notes for a class in advanced methods in QFT. No book